# C# - Are properties recalculated everytime they are accessed?

Tags: c#, properties

Assuming the following simple code:

```
private const int A = 2;
private const int B = 3;


public int Result
    {
        get
        {
            return A * B;
        }
    }
```

I am using the Result property a lot of times.
Is the product A*B recalculated every time?

Comment: Is your example meant to cover mulitplying constants **only**, or are you more after how properties work in general? As others have noted the constants will get optimized down; however, if you aren't really using constants then there are other answers...

Comment: Actually, it was both, but I didn't know there was such an important difference or I would have clarified it. Most cases I need are: 1) simple multiplication of two constants and I was wondering if there should be a private field to save the variable. 2) Long operations that are actually only needed to performed once but the compiler cannot possibly know that like in the const case.

Comment: Correcting my previous comment, this was mostly a question on constants specifically. I was unsure whether the compiler can figure out that A*B is also a constant, thus obviating the need to declare another const C = A*B.

Comment: In that case, you don't need a private field as the compiler will figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening up the assembly in reflector, the compiler will optimize the multiplication since they are `const int`:

```
public class FooContainer
{
    private const int A = 2;
    private const int B = 3;


    public int Result
    {
        get
        {
            return A * B;
        }
    }
}
```

Will become:

```
public class FooContainer
{
    // Fields
    private const int A = 2;
    private const int B = 3;

    // Properties
    public int Result
    {
        get
        {
            return 6;
        }
    }
}
```

But if you change the variables to simply `int` and do not store the computation the evaluation will occur each time.

Example:

```
public class FooContainer
{
    private int A = 2;
    private const int B = 3;


    public int Result
    {
        get
        {
            return A * B;
        }
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```
public class FooContainer
{
    // Fields
    private int A = 2;
    private const int B = 3;

    // Properties
    public int Result
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.A * 3);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A really good compiler, besides implementing the function like this, would actually replace the *call site* with the constant.  That isn't always possible, depending on the context of the call.

Comment: Nice, exactly what I was looking for. @Ira Baxter: Just to clarify, do you mean that a really good compiler _would_ do this? Or does the .net/mono compiler actually do this right now as Mark demonstrated?

Comment: @Danimoth: as my answer indicated, the compiler might do this. You dont get any guarantees that optimizations you'd like to have happen, actually do happen. I'd expect it to be more likely in .net than mono, because MS has more resources and time.

Comment: In the case of non `const` declarations, what's the difference then between a getter and a parameterless method Result()?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't store the value in a private field, then yes it's going to recalculate upon every access.

A way to cache the results would be to

```
private int? _result;
public int Result {
  get {
     if (!_result.HasValue) {
       _result = A*B;
     }
     return _result.Value;
  }
}
```

**There are several caveats here.**

*First*, if all of your operations are against constants then the compiler will automatically optimize those away for you.  Which means that the multiplication operation won't actually be performed at run time.  Which means you shouldn't worry about it.

*Second*, if the operation is limited to performing a simple arithmetic operation against two existing variables, then computing it each time would be faster than the "if" test above.  Also, local storage with a private field in this case would increase your memory footprint for no useful reason.

*Third*, if the underlying variables had *changed* between calls to the property getter (i.e. A or B has a new value), then this would **NOT** recompute with those new values.

Which leaves us with one of the few reasons to actually use the above code: The operation takes a long time and the data it operates on isn't changing between calls to the property.  The only other reason I can think of at this moment to use this is if the property is an object that has to be instantiated before calling.

Comment: It is? I'd think `A * B` was a constant expression as it multiplies two constants, and the compiler would optimize that to `6` - or does it make exceptions for properties?

Comment: I'm assuming that was just an example to show some computation. I doubt the poster is concerned about the performance of multiplying two numbers together.

Comment: @BoltClock: AFAIK there is no exception - A * B is also constant, and its result will be calculated during compilation.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'd agree that the compiler would probably just optimize out multiplying two constants, but I figured the OP was just providing a quick example.

Comment: @chaiguy: The OP did specifically say "Is the product A*B recalculated every time?", so I wasn't too sure.

Comment: even if they are not constants this is bad: if the compiler does not do some magic on the 'if' the if (!){} (cmp,xor,jmp in assembly) you introduced will be much slower than a multiply (mul) so this 'optimization' will be slower than simply multiplying :) more so this will stress more on branch prediction on the cpu... if those variables are in the cpu cache this operation will be an out of order operation without the if and will run on cpu spare resource time

Comment: @Marino: You are absolutely correct that the if statement would take longer to run.  I'll add a note to the main body of my answer

Comment: I mostly wanted to know about the compiler's behavior on constants, but insight on other cases mentioned is also appreciated :)

Comment: Can't you just compare it to `default` instead of using nullable `int?`?

Comment: Also, you can calculate it in the setter each time `A` or `B` changes.

Comment: or set it to `null` when `A` or `B` changes but then it will be recalculated only when accessed, not immediately

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing magical about properties. They're just syntactic sugar over two methods, `get_Xxx` and `set_Xxx`. Knowing that, it's clear that every time a property is accessed, all code inside `get` part gets executed.

Answer (score 2):

Since the values are `const`, the compiler might optimize this situation.

But if they aren't `const`, it will be calculated each time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. However, a good rule of thumb here is that if you want an operation like this, it should be a method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, properties are just special methods that are executed each time they are accessed. If you want to cache the results, store it in a member variable, perhaps a nullable int, and check to see if it has been calculated or not before returning it (also known as lazy initialization):

```
int? _result = null;
public int Result {
    get {
        if ( _result == null )
            _result = A * B;
        return _result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most languages don't define how optimizations work. The usual language-lawyer phrase is "as if", and in this case, the C# definition is pretty likely to say "the value of the property on each call is returned *as if* it were evaluated".  That gives the compiler types freedom to do anything that preserves the documented behavior.

So, the compiler *might* optimize this.  Usually, compilers with a long history and an emphasis on performance (C# has a long history and lots of resources, not quite such an emphasis on performance) try to figure out under what circumstances a previously computed result can be reused.  The fact that your A and B are declared as CONSTS suggests the compiler can figure out that the product is a constant, and that in fact it could replace every call on the getter with the const.

It could.  Whether it does is an open question.  I doubt Microsoft will answer this question in a "yes it absolutely does this" way.

Comment: I see. Then, to be on the safe side, maybe the best option would be to just declare a const C = A*B for cases like that.

Comment: @Danimoth: if the performance of this property matters, that might make sense. But that's a different question: does it actually matter? Before you hand-optimize this, you should verify it is problem. Otherwise you are just wasting your time and making maintenance harder for the next guy.  I suspect based on experience with x86s that *calling* the property is more expensive than doing the arithmetic and I suspect you have less control over whether it is called or inlined, so even after your optimize the multiply, you might not have much impact.

Answer (score 0):

The property is evaluated every time it's called.  If you want something more efficient, you have to handle it yourself.